# Data not fetched from second table after using where clause PHP/MYSql (SQL Joins)

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

My sql query is to return title,date from one table and image name from another table using join based on Ad ID.

Here is the same.This works perfectly and fetches all data title, date from table 1 and image name from table 2.

```
SELECT wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title,  
wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id,wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_postdate,
wordpresswp_awpcp_media.name FROM wordpresswp_awpcp_ads 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wordpresswp_awpcp_media on wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id = wordpresswp_awpcp_media.ad_id
```

Now for alphabet wise query i.e display ads staring with A,B.... I have passed a query in URL and rewrote the query as

```
SELECT wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title, wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id, 
wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_postdate,wordpresswp_awpcp_media.name FROM wordpresswp_awpcp_ads 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wordpresswp_awpcp_media on wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id = wordpresswp_awpcp_media.ad_id 
WHERE (wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title LIKE '$directory%' )
```

$directory takes alphabet passed from URL. With this query I am able to fetch data from table 1 i,e title name and date from not able to get the data from joined table i.e image name from table 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @ raveenanigam no error is throws and no data wrt table 2 is displayed.

Comment: Please share your table structure

Comment: @raveenanigam  http://i58.tinypic.com/io2hbn.png

http://i60.tinypic.com/qno0fc.png

Comment: Your code and table structure seems right. Please check whatever title you are searching respective image is there or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title, wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id,  
   wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_postdate,wordpresswp_awpcp_media.name   
FROM wordpresswp_awpcp_ads 
INNER JOIN wordpresswp_awpcp_media   
ON wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id = wordpresswp_awpcp_media.ad_id 
WHERE (wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title LIKE '$directory%' )
```

Comment: thanks but when i am try this all results are displayed as if no filter and data from table 2 is also not fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I guess you got into the classics.

When you add a `where` condition about your left joined table, then you get only rows which have that left join. So make sure you do not create a `where`-condition about `wordpresswp_awpcp_media`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yeap I am getting only left side rows along with join of right side rows. This works perfectly. But what happens is that after I get this result I tried to filter it based on alphabet where its breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I think php variable is in single comm (') that's the problem please try

```
SELECT wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title, wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id, 
wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_postdate,wordpresswp_awpcp_media.name FROM wordpresswp_awpcp_ads 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wordpresswp_awpcp_media on wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_id = wordpresswp_awpcp_media.ad_id 
WHERE (wordpresswp_awpcp_ads.ad_title LIKE "$directory%" )
```